# body.unload in Safari for Windows

Tags: safari-extension

so I have a Safari extension, and the following works well in Safari for Mac, but not in Safari for Windows.... (from my Global.html):

```
<body onload='initialize()' onunload='quit()'>
```

is there some kind of workaround to get this to work on Windows?
I am wanting to capture the Safari has been quit event....

I also tried using the close event:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("close", closed, true);
```

but I can't find a way to narrow this down to just the window close event. I get messages for each tab closure.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I also posted this over on the Apple forums, and received this answer, which works well in windows: "If you want to listen for when a window closes, in your close event, you can put:
 
if (event.target instanceof SafariBrowserWindow) {
    // do your closing window logic here
}"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library, which you should be, it should help with this.

For instance, I believe jquery's unload fixes it. Install jquery and use the following:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  // do something
});
```